# jqGrid new setup giving JS error: ts undefined

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am trying play around with jqGrid (and a few others). Doing the initial setup for jqGrid is giving me a JS error. I must have imported the scripts in wrong order or something silly, but being so new to that widget its hard for me to figure it out.

Here is the page that is giving me the problem (go there and see error for yourself):

http://programmingdrunk.com/table-test/

This is the example which is found here:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html -> "new in 3.5" -> "integrated search bar"

the exact error firebug reports is:

```
ts is not defined
[Break on this error] th = $("<th role='columnheader' clas...olumn ui-th-"+ts.p.direction+"'></th>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer: i was using 3.6 beta. i switched to 3.5.2 stable and stuff worked